# bulk records taking too much time to save in Redis when using CrudRepository.saveAll(..)

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to save 1 million records in redis throuhg redis repository but when I save it take almost 4 minutes to save it, my code is as follows

```
public interface ActionEventTypesModelRepository extends CrudRepository<ActionEventTypesModel, String> {
List<ActionEventTypesModel> findByActionEventTypeCd(String actionEventTypeCd);

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@RedisHash("ActionEventTypes")
public class ActionEventTypesModel {

    @Id
    private Double actionEventId;
    @Indexed
    private String actionEventTypeCd;
    private String actionEventTypeDesc;

}

repository.saveAll(actionEventTypesModel );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [Redis pipelining](https://redis.io/docs/manual/pipelining/), which is supported by Spring Data Redis (see [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#pipeline)).

Under-the-hood, Spring Data (Redis)'s Repository infrastructure uses the `RedisTemplate` to perform the Repository CRUD operations, like `CrudRepository.saveAll(..)`.

You could split up your data set into chunks passed to `saveAll(..)` based on your configured pipeline parameters (like buffer size).

I would also say the `(String)RedisTemplate` will afford you more control when "executing" in a pipeline (see [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html); specifically, the `executePipelined(..)` overloaded methods). So, if you are simply bulk loading data, e.g. on startup, then the `(String)RedisTemplate` may be a better option.